# 12.04 can't connect to 64 bit WEP

Tags: 12.04, wireless, 32-bit

I'm an absolute beginner to Linux, and I already have a problem. Go me!

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit on my desktop PC, dual booted with my previously installed Windows XP.

I have a 64 bit WEP encrypted Wireless connection that I can't change because I want to connect my DSi and Wii to the internet and they only accept 64 bit WEP encryption.

On Windows XP I can connect with no problem at all, but on Ubuntu it tries to connect, but after a few minutes asks again for my password. I checked it many times, and it's entered 100% correctly.

I have searched all over the internet for possible solutions, since it seems to be a VERY common problem, but nothing I tried worked.

So, any suggestions from someone more experienced than me would be extremely appreciated.
Thank you in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there are 64bit WEP networks at all. And I think Wii does understand WPA after an update.
In ubuntu is the kernel used to deliver drivers for Hardware. If your computer is newer, you should use the newest version of ubuntu with the newer kernel.
As an user of XP I would use the lxde Version of ubuntu, lubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu.

Comment: My password is in the form of "1111AA1A1A", which I think is 64-bit. Both my router and my PC are quite old.